# In express, how do I route to a custom error template when a condition is met?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, pug

In my select statement, if the parameter from the URL is not correct, I want to send the user to a custom error template.

I've tried setting up the render, but the parameters passed aren't working.

```
#routes.js
router.get('/select-id/', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.query.id;
    if(id && id.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null){
        mc('SELECT * FROM tasks where ID = ' + id, function (error, results, fields) {
         if (error) throw error;
          res.render('pug-select-all', {
            title: 'Results',
            data: results
          });
        });
    }
    else {
        res.render('error', {status: 500, stack: 'error'});
    }
});
```

```
#error.pug
extends layout

block content
  h1= message
  h2= error.status
  pre #{error.stack}
```

I've tried different things, but I either always get an error on the routes.js or pug template.  If I leave it like the code above, I get `Cannot read property 'status' of undefined` in error.pug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs, you should either send your response object as:

```
res.render('error', { "error": {status: 500, stack: 'error' } });
```

**Or** in your `pug` template, access it as *first level* member like:

```
#error.pug
extends layout

block content
  h1= message
  h2= status
  pre #{stack}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me

```
res.status(404).render('errorPage', {
  title: '404 - page nt found!'
});
```

for your needs it could be

```
res.status(500).render('error', {
  status: 500, 
  stack: 'error'
});
```